# N-queens puzzle in Java with 1D array

Tags: java, arrays, n-queens

I am working a problem that seems to be somewhat famous among beginning programmers, the 8 queens puzzle. I have seen several solutions to this problems using 2D arrays, recursion etc, but this problem is an assignment given in CS course book chapter introducing 1D arrays, so the available techniques to solve this problem are limited.

The procedure I have used, is by first creating a 1D array with the size of 64, which makes possible positions to place queens from index 0 to 63. A random position index is then generated, and a test is preformed to check if there is any queens attacking this position. If this position is not attacked by any queens, a queen is placed by setting the `board[position] = true`. When a queen is placed, the `queenCount` is incremented, and this process repeats until 8 queens have been placed.

If queens are placed in such a way that it is impossible to place 8, the board resets after 1 millisecond by preforming a timecheck, and retries to place the 8 queens. At the best I am able to place 7 queens, but the last remaining one is never placed. Each attempt is printed, along with `queenCount` for this attempt. Is it possible to use this approach, or is it a dead end?

Code example below:

```
package ch7;

public class Chapter_07_E22_EightQueens64bool {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int queenCount = 0;
        int attemptCount = 0;
        boolean[] board = new boolean[8 * 8];
        final long TIME_LIMIT = 1; //Milliseconds

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (queenCount < 8) {

                int position = placeQueen(board.length);

                if(checkPosition(position, board) && !board[position]) {
                    board[position] = true;
                    queenCount++;
                }

                long timeCheck = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (timeCheck - startTime > TIME_LIMIT) {
                    clearBoard(board);
                    queenCount = 0;
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }         
            System.out.println("Attempt #" + ++attemptCount);
            System.out.println(queenCount + " queens placed.");
            printBoard(board);
        }   
    }      

    public static void printBoard(boolean[] board) {

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

            if (board[i])
                System.out.print("|Q");
            else
                System.out.print("| ");

            if ((i + 1) % 8 == 0)
                System.out.println("|");    
        }
    }

    public static int placeQueen(int boardSize) {
        return (int)(Math.random() * boardSize);
    } 

    public static boolean[] clearBoard(boolean[] board) {

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
            board[i] = false;

        return board;

    }

    public static boolean checkPosition(int position, boolean[] board) {

        return checkTop(position, board) && checkBottom(position, board) && checkLeft(position, board) &&
               checkRight(position, board) && checkTopLeft(position, board) && checkTopRight(position, board) &&
               checkBottomLeft(position, board) && checkBottomRight(position, board);
    }

    public static boolean checkTop(int position, boolean[] board) {
        // Checks each field above the current position while i >= 8  
        for (int i = position; i >= 8; i -= 8) {
            if (board[i - 8])
                    return false;  
        }
        return true;                
    }

    public static boolean checkBottom(int position, boolean[] board) {
        // Checks each field below the current position while i <= 55;
        for (int i = position; i <= 55; i += 8) {
            if (board[i + 8])
                    return false;
        }
        return true;                
    }

    public static boolean checkRight(int position, boolean[] board) {
        // Checks each field to the right of the current position while i % 8 < 7
        for (int i = position; i % 8 < 7; i += 1) {
            if (board[i + 1])
                return false;

        }
        return true;                
    }

    public static boolean checkLeft(int position, boolean[] board) {
        // Checks each field to the left of the current position while i % 8 != 0
        for (int i = position; i % 8 != 0; i -= 1) {
            if (board[i - 1])
                return false;  
        }
        return true;                
    }

    public static boolean checkTopLeft(int position, boolean[] board) {
        // Checks each field top left of the current position while i >= 9
        for (int i = position; i >= 9; i -= 9) {
            if (board[i - 9])
                return false;   
        }
        return true;                
    }

    public static boolean checkTopRight(int position, boolean[] board) {
        // Checks each field top right of the current position while i >= 7   
        for (int i = position; i >= 7; i -= 7) {
            if (board[i - 7])
                return false;   
        }
        return true;                
    }

    public static boolean checkBottomRight(int position, boolean[] board) {
        // Checks each field below the current position while i <= 54
        for (int i = position; i <= 54; i += 9) {
            if (board[i + 9])
                return false;    
        }
        return true;                
    }

    public static boolean checkBottomLeft(int position, boolean[] board) {
        // Checks each field below the current position while i <= 56
        for (int i = position; i <= 56; i += 7) {
            if (board[i + 7])
                return false;   
        }
        return true;                
    }

}
```

Comment: by "the while loop breaks" do you mean it loops infinitely?

Comment: I guess thats what i meant, the program makes n number of attempts to place the 8 queens, until it is not able to place anymore. However, I have seen on the output that it should have been possible to place 1 or 2 more.

Comment: Is there a check to make sure queens aren't occupying the same spot?

Comment: I added now one, but now it loops infinitely. It seems the first solution placed queens in positions that was already occupied. Edited the code so the check to verify that queens occupying the same spot is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working on this problem for a few days, I now have a solution that works that in a reasonable amount of time for N <= 20. It goes like this.

1. `For i < N`, initialize `queens[i] = i`. Each row can only hold 1 value, so no need to check for collisions on the left or right. As long as there is no duplicate values in the array, there will not be any column collisions either.
2. Use the method to check if a queen at a given point, shares a diagonal with a queen at another given point.  The method checks to see if the distance between x1 and x0 is equal to the distance of y1 and y0. If the distance is equal, then the co-ordinates (x0,y0) and (x1,y1) share the same diagonal.
3. Use another method to invoke `shareDiagonal(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)` to check if a queen at a given row, for example on row 7, collides with a queen on any rows above row 7. As mentioned, only the rows above the given row are checked. The reason is that if you for example are checking row2 for any diagonal collisions, any collision with rows below row 2 will be revealed when checking a row with a higher index value. If a queen on row 2 collides with a queen on row 4, this will be revealed when checking row 4 and the rows above.
4. A third checking method invokes  `checkRowForCollision(int[] queens, int row)`, where each row is traversed checking for collisions on the rows above. Row 1 is checked if there is any collisions with queens on row 0, Row 2 is checked if there is any collisions on row 0 and 1, row 3 is checked if there is any collisions on row 0, 1 and 2, etc..
5. While there is diagonal collisions between any of the queens, the board shuffles until it shows a solution where no queens attack each other.

Code example below:

```
package ch7;

public class Chapter_07_E22_EightQueens {

    static final int N = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] queens = new int[N];
        int attempts = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
            queens[i] = i;

        while (checkBoardForCollision(queens)) {
            shuffleBoard(queens);
            attempts++;
        }
        printBoard(queens);
        System.out.println("Solution found in " + attempts + " attempts");
    }

    public static void printBoard(int[] queens) {

        for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
            System.out.printf("%-1c", '|');
            for (int column = 0; column < N; column++) {
                System.out.printf("%-1c|", (queens[row] == column) ? 'Q' : ' ');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }       
    }

    public static boolean shareDiagonal(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {

        int dy = Math.abs(y1 - y0);
        int dx = Math.abs(x1 - x0);

        return dx == dy;
    }

    public static boolean checkRowForCollision(int[] queens, int row) {

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {

            if (shareDiagonal(i, queens[i], row, queens[row]))
                return true;    
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean checkBoardForCollision(int[] queens) {

        for (int row = 0; row < queens.length; row++)
            if (checkRowForCollision(queens, row))
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    public static int[] shuffleBoard(int[] queens) {

        for (int i = queens.length - 1;  i > 0; i--) {

            int j = (int)(Math.random() * (i + 1));

            int temp = queens[i];
            queens[i] = queens[j];
            queens[j] = temp;
        }
        return queens;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, array of size 8 is perfectly sufficient.
The array *index* represents the *column* in which was the queen placed and the *value* represents the *row*.

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Means that queen in the first column was placed in the first row, second queen was placed in the 3rd row, 3rd queen in 5th row, etc...

So when you place a new queen, check if the row you add it in, isn't already in the array. This way, you only need to worry about diagonal collisions.

Simplest way of solving the problem is **recursion** (backtracking). If that is not allowed, you can simulate recursion with a **stack**. If that is not allowed either, you could use 8 **nested loops** - ugly.

---

You can improve your collision checking using a simple trick. It works like this -
Let's say your queen #0 is on row #3.
Which cells does she attack diagonally?
On the first column, it's row #2 and row #4 (`-1` and `+1`)
On the second column, it's row #1 and row #5 (`-2` and `+2`)
On the third column it's row #0 and row #6 (`-3` and `+3`)
So when you add a new queen, you iterate previous queens checking one diagonal with `(newIndex - oldIndex) + oldRow == newRow` and the other diagonal with `(newIndex - oldIndex) - oldRow == newRow`

So, considering all this, the checking function could look like

```
boolean canAdd(List<Integer> p, int newRow) {
    if (p.contains(newRow))
        return false;
    int insertIndex = p.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
        if (p.get(i) + (insertIndex - i) == newRow || p.get(i) - (insertIndex - i) == newRow)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

While the main recursive function could look like

```
void solve(List<Integer> p, int index) {
    if (index == 8) {
        System.out.println(p);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (canAdd(p, i)) {
            p.add(i);
            solve(p, index + 1);
            p.remove(p.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

And you could call it like this

```
solve(new ArrayList<Integer>(), 0);
```

Comment: After trying to improve the procedure i was already working on, i figured it's nok going to work. My solution is able to place 7 queens at most, but when the last one is going to be placed, there are no free slots. I found a solution on a blog using a similiar approach to the one you are describing, and this solution works. I will try to wrap my head around it.  Thanks for input !

Comment: @Esben86 no problem, don't hesitate to ask if you have more questions.

Comment: I have created an array with 8 slots, where the index 0 to 7 represents each row, and these slots should be filled with values from 0 to 7, where each value represents the column the queens i placed in. When creating an array, all slots have the value 0, which means i already have 8 queens lined up in column 0. I thought that the board should be clean before placing any queens, but since each slot in the array has the value 0 by default, this would be impossible. At the moment, the first queen can never be placed at [0] = 0, [1] = 0 etc, since there is always a queen standing below.

Comment: Well, my approach for solving this problem was a little different - place first queen anywhere. Place second queen somewhere, where it isn't attacked by first queen. Place third queen somewhere where it isn't attacked by all previously placed queens. And so on...This way, you know for sure that before you place a new queen, no queens on board attack each other, so you need to check only the one you are currently placing...

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems, there may be more though, is in the `checkTop` method.

```
public static boolean checkTop(int position, boolean[] board)
{
    // Checks each field above the current position while i - 8 > - 1
    for (int i = position; i > (i - 8); i -= 8)
    {
        if ((i - 8) > -1)
        {
            if (board[i - 8])
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

There are cases when the method doesn't find a slot (`board[i - 8] = true`) and `i` reaches the value of `7`. After this point, the condition of the `for loop` (`i > (i - 8)`) will always be `true` and the condition of the outermost `if` inside the loop (`if ( (i - 8) > -1`) will always be `false`. This causes the program to infinitely stay in the loop.

Example (`i` reaches -5):

```
i = -5;
i > ( i - 8) :  -5 > (-5 -8 = -13) (always true) 
(i - 8) > -1 :  -13 > -1           (false) always false for i <= 7
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I believe some of the other methods for collision check might have similiar problems. I will try to do some more work on these.