# Diagonally check the n queen JAVA

Tags: java, n-queens

I am having a problem about understanding the code i got online. It's the checking of the queen if there's a collision with other queens. Can somebody explain to me what does this do? The first condition, I knew it's the checking of the same row, but what about the absolute number?

```
if ((board[i] == board[row]) || Math.abs(board[row] - board[i]) == (row - i)) 
{
     return false;
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
class NQueen {

private int[] board;
private int size;
private ArrayList allSolutions = null;

public int[] getBoard() {
    return board;
}
public ArrayList getAllSolutions() {
    return this.allSolutions;
}
public NQueen(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    board = new int[this.size];
    this.allSolutions = new ArrayList();
}
public void place(int row) {
            // base case
    if (row == size) {
        int[] temp = new int[size];
                    // copy in temp array
        System.arraycopy(board, 0, temp, 0, size);
                    // add to the list of solution
        allSolutions.add(new Solution(temp));
        return ;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            board[row] = i;
                            /* when you place a new queen
                             * check if the row you add it in, isn't 
                             * already in the array. since the value of arrray is
                             * the row, so we only need to check the diagonals no need to check for collisions on the left or right. 
                             * As long as there is no duplicate values in the array.*/
            if (valid(row)){
                               place(row + 1);
                            }

        }
    }
}
public boolean valid(int row) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                    // if same row  or same diagonal
        if ((board[i] == board[row]) || Math.abs(board[row] - board[i]) == (row - i)) 
                    {
                        return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: What is board? What type of array is it? What values does it store? Which part of the movement are you trying to check - horizontal, vertical or diagonal?

Comment: It would be helpful to think of StackOverflow users as friendly neighborhood strangers, who don't know anything at all about your problem or code. Explain your question in as much detail as possible.

Comment: The array index represents the column in which was the queen placed and the value represents the row. The condition (board[i] == board[row]) probably checks for the same row, but according to what I read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35371519/n-queens-puzzle-in-java-with-1d-array the  Math.abs(board[row] - board[i]) == (row - i)) would probably check for the diagonals.

Comment: Anyway, I should add the entire code

Comment: The board variable likely stores for each row the column where a queen is placed. Row is the variable for the current row. i is a loop variable going over all previous rows. E.g. if we place a queen in column 2 or row 2, we need to check if there is a queen in column 2 of row 1, or any queen in column 1 or 3. It's easier to understand when drawing the board

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a 2-dimensional array and each position on the board "cell" in the array, then to be in the same diagonal, a piece have to have the same horizontal and vertical distance.

```
Math.abs(board[row] - board[i]) == (row - i)
```

Checks exactly that. The `Math.abs` is because the second piece can be top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left. Not sure how exactly your algorithm is implemented, but it's probably a good idea to take the absolute value of the second operand too.

Example with a small board:

```
  1 2 3 4
1
2 x
3
4     y
```

So here we have a horizontal distance of 2 (abs(1-3)) and a vertical distance also of 2 (abs(2-4))

Example 2:

```
  1 2 3 4
1       x
2     y
3 
4
```

Here we have only horizontal and vertical distance of only 1 (abs(4-3) and abs(1-2))

#### Follow up

Your array stores in each element the position of the queen in this row. So it is only a one-dimensional array (not two dimensional as originally suggested by me).

So for my first example your array would contain:

```
[ 0, 1, 0, 3 ]
```

(I think the code from the OP assumes 0-based positions but initializes the array elements with `0` (`new int[size]`). *This might be a bug*, because 0 is a valid position and could conflict with other constraints, i.e. you will not be able to place a queen on index 1 if the queen from the previous or next row is uninitialized (=position 0).)

Back to the example (using 1-based indices for clarity and to avoid the bug mentioned above): `a[2] - a[4] == 1 - 3` (`a[2] == 1`, `a[4] == 3`)

If the "y" piece was moved to column 2 instead, then you would get `a[2] - a[4] != 1 - 3`, because they do not share the diagonal (`a[2] == 1`, `a[4] == 3`)

Comment: And because you iterate always in the same direction and stop at `row`, the expression `row - i` is guaranteed to be non-negative.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! But what about the bug? because it does have a bug, when displaying the GUI it says Index out of bounds, what should I initialize then?

Comment: index of out bounds is something else. Index of out bounds means that you access `a[size]` (but an array of size `size` has its last element at index `size-1`, so `a[size-1]`). `a[0]` is a valid position (and therefor the "column" 0 is also valid). In your case, I would simply initialize the array elements with an invalid/magic value such as `-1` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE` – these values will never match your diagonals